# Highchart - Guage chart always pointing to 10 with decimal value during **point.update()**

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

i want to update the values as decimals for a guage chart **point.update([my decimal value])**. But it always points to 10. It works only when i supply an integer value.

Heres the yAxis definition -

```
 yAxis: [{

                    lineWidth: 0,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 10,
                    tickInterval :100,
                    tickPosition: 'outside',
                    minorTickPosition: 'outside',
                    tickLength: 15,
                    minorTickLength: 0,
                    labels: {
                        distance: 25
                    },
                    offset: 5,
                    endOnTick: false,
                    title: {
                        y: -70
                    },

                    plotOptions: {
                        solidgauge: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                y: 5,
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                useHTML: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }],
```

and the series is

```
series: [{
                    name: 'Speed',

                    data: [{
                        id: 'hour',
                        y: 10,
                        dial: {
                            backgroundColor: '#DEA12F',
                            radius: '100%',
                            baseLength: '5%',
                            baseWidth: 15,
                            rearLength: '0%'
                        }

                    }],
```

Here is the pic of the dial with the values

[image]

How can make the dial to point to the specified value(0.9)?

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo ?

Comment: Requires demo. Standard gauge usage supports decimal-values.